# Java 7 to migration compatibility issue

Tags: java, scala, java-8, scalding, unsupported-class-version

After migrating the jobs from java 7 to 8 getting following error,even though compilation is successful.

Same version of java i.e java 8 was used in compilation and the same version is being used while runtime. So typically there should be any mismatch in the version of java.Even scala version are same.

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:59)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:51)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at com.twitter.scalding.RichXHandler$.<init>(XHandler.scala:38)
        at com.twitter.scalding.RichXHandler$.<clinit>(XHandler.scala)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Tool$.main(Tool.scala:152)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.main(Tool.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:56)
```

Comment: Looks like you upgraded jar file containing package `com.twitter.scalding`, but didn't upgrade Scala Runtime Library to match.

Comment: Scala run-time library is same as HDP 2.5.3